# Using intel's tbb with qt

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, intel, tbb

I've qt 4.8 with gcc 4.6.1 and I'd like to use intel's tbb in my project. What steps am I suppose to do in order to do that?

Answer (score 4):

- Install tbb (including headers and libs)
- Include the headers where necessary
- Use the library where appropriate.
- Link with tbb

Comment: You're talking about installing tbb, yet the only thing I was able to find: http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/download.php doesn't have installator. It is just zipped file.

Comment: What OS, what version, what system architecture... it was a pretty vauge question with a pretty vague answer

Comment: OS Windows 7, architecture x86

Comment: So toy are using miniGW or cgywin or something? If so then your question should be how to install tbb on cygwin or something like that

Comment: I have qt and gcc never heard of miniGW, don't have cygwin

Comment: Sorry I just don't anything about windows, I can't help you

Comment: ... assuming you use QtCreator: unzip to a directory, add the full path to the dll to your LIBS in your .pro file, add include directory to your INCLUDEPATH in your .pro file. Done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to build TBB dll files for MingW using this command

```
mingw32-make compiler=gcc arch=ia32 runtime=mingw tbb
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807406/building-linking-to-tbb-under-mingw) in the directory where the main TBB Makefile is.

Comment: @sad_mad I did it. Now for some bizarre reason I'm getting error that exception_ptr isn't a type even though I can see this header in bits/ directory

Comment: @smallB: seems like TBB tried to use C++11 features (namely, exception propagation) but the compiler did not enable it. Perhaps the TBB forum is a better place than SO to get it resolved.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov: Indeed, the compiler is configured to disable it, by default. The question of #smallB is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9537219/425817).I may ask the same thing in TBB forums as well.